# How do I earn the "Mad Dash" achievement?

Tags: achievements, 100-percent-orange-juice

The description for the "Mad Dash" achievement in 100% Orange Juice says "*A maddening display of speed*". I haven't been able to figure out what this vague description actually means.

[image: Mad Dash achievement]

How do I earn the Mad Dash achievement in 100% Orange Juice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this guide](https://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/732625-100-orange-juice/achievements):

> **Mad Dash**
>   Travel at least twelve tiles from Roll Again tiles in one turn